# How to validate that the date is from today <javascript>

Tags: javascript, date

I have this function which consists in validating a date entered by the user. So far I only check that the date format is correct (dd/mm/yyyy).

But, I also wanted to check that the date entered is today's date, not a prior or future date.

I thought of something like `var currentdate = new Date();` and then compare both, but I have not tinkered with dates yet and didn't want to mess it up. Any ideas how I should write it?.

```
function validate(){
var date = $("#dateentry").val();

if (/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(date)){
   $("#msg").html("The date format is correct");
 }else{
   $("#msg").html("The date format must be dd/mm/yyyy");
 }

}
```

Comment: what is the input type of dateentry?

Comment: @user2181397 It is a simple input with type text.

Comment: Would you consider using a library. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ has many useful functions for this sort of thing.

Comment: Hope you realize `'31/04/2016'` and `'29/02/2017`' are both invalid dates but will pass your regex...

Comment: @MattJohnson—"*So far I only check that the date format is correct*". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think your only choice is comparison with the date today.

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
if(new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0) >= todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
{
    $("#msg").html("Date should not be prior or greater that current date");
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting parsing a string in format d/m/y using the Date constructor, which is not a good idea. It will not provide the expected result except for dates where the day and month number are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should always manually parse date strings, especially if they aren't the format included in ECMA-262 (ISO 8601 extended format).

A function to parse and validate a date in d/m/y format is below. You can then check if it's today or not by creating a date for today, setting the time to 00:00:00 and comparing:

```js
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = (''||s).match(/\d+/g);
  var d = new Date(b[2]||0, (b[1]||0)-1, b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]-1? d : new Date(NaN);
}

var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log('Today is: ' + today);

// Returns true on 15 June 2016
var s = '15/06/2016';
console.log('Is today ' + s + '? ' + (parseDMY(s).getTime() == today.getTime()))
```

This also removes the need test the values entered separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `input type="date"` you can disable the previous dates, thus avoiding any validation

Hope this snippet will be useful

HTML

```
<input type="date" name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
```

`JS`

```
var dateTime = document.getElementById("dateTime").value;
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementById("dateTime").setAttribute('min', today);
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jjsm68ru/1/)

Comment: And in browsers that don't support input type date? Also, *toISOString* returns a date in GMT timezone, so the date may be different to the host date.